# Which algorithms typify Lisp's power?

Tags: algorithms, lisp

Similar question [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/154426/what-are-examples-of-lisps-accomplishments) (but not the same) because I am interested in which specific algorithms work particularly well in Lisp.

Lisp tutorials always give the example of finding factorials, but wanting to find factorials is not a good enough motivation to use Lisp.

I've heard that Quicksort has a particularly elegant implementation in Lisp. Can you give examples (and code samples too) of examples of algorithms that are best implemented in a language like Lisp?

Comment: Phil, get a copy of the SICP book (or read it online here http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) to get some insights for what Lisp is good for. Don't try to reduce it to "algorithm X is better implemented in Lisp than in <???>" - this does not really work. In the current form, the question is IMHO not constructive, since it could lead to endless discussions, thus voting to close.

Comment: If the factorial function is the only algorithms you have seen in Lisp, you probably haven't read "Practical Common Lisp" (http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Answer (score 2):

Lisp is not a one-trick pony, not even a two or ten thousand trick pony.

> “Please don't assume Lisp is only useful for Animation and Graphics, AI, Bioinformatics, B2B and Ecommerce, Data Mining, EDA/Semiconductor applications, Expert Systems, Finance, Intelligent Agents, Knowledge Management, Mechanical CAD, Modeling and Simulation, Natural Language, Optimization, Research, Risk Analysis, Scheduling, Telecom, and Web Authoring just because these are the only things they happened to list.” ([kmp](http://www.nhplace.com/kent/quoted.html))

If you want to see many algorithms implemented in Lisp, get a book (e.g., [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) or [PCL](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/)).

See also [Why is Lisp used for AI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130475/why-is-lisp-used-for-ai)